# What is the 30th number in the sequence?

Tags: mathematics, number-sequence

What is the 30th number in the following sequence?

> 0, 2, 4, 12, 8, 20, 24, 56, 16, 36, ...

I'm not sure what would be good hints, or how much further out I should list the sequence. I figure the first ten values should be a good start, but I can add or confirm more if needed.

BTW, The first six are sufficient to show that this sequence does not appear on the [Online Encyclopedia of Integer Sequences](http://oeis.org).

Comment: There are an infinite number of justifiable solutions.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I would say that the 30th number in the sequence is:

> $464$

Explanation:

> Let $H(n)$ be the [Hamming weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_weight) of a number $n$, where the 
>  Hamming weight is the sum of all the 1s in the binary representation of $n$.
>
>  Starting with $n = 0$, each number in the sequence $S(n)$ is $n \times 2^{H(n)}$.
>
>  For example, for $n = 5$, the binary representation of $5$ is $101$, and $H(5)$
>  is $2$.  Thus the 6th element in the sequence is $5 \times 2^2 = 20. $
>
>  By this logic, the 30th element of the sequence has $n = 29$.  The binary representation of $29$ is $11101$, so $H(29)$ is $4$.  Thus the 30th element is $29 \times 2^4 = 464$.

Comment: Googling the sequence also worked :)

Comment: How did you arrive at this?

Comment: @PierreDuc Nothing *useful* comes up when I google the sequence (I get the sequence but no information on how it was arrived at)

Comment: @question_asker Googling "0, 2, 4, 12, 8, 20, 24, 56, 16, 36" (with quotes) gave me [http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~dmaslov/hwb9.txt](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~dmaslov/hwb9.txt)... if you then go to [http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~dmaslov/](http://webhome.cs.uvic.ca/~dmaslov/) and search for `hwb9` you find: `Hidden weighted bit functions` :D

Comment: @question_asker I just sort of noticed that each number S(n) in the sequence was divisible by n itself (it jumped out at me that 56 was 7*8, 24 was 6*4, 20 was 5*4, etc.) so I divided each term by it's "index" in the list and was left with 2 2 4 2 4 4 8 2 4 ... Obviously all being powers of 2, so I looked at them in binary and noticed the pattern.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the 30th number in the sequence is:

> 28141044420

Explanation:

> With the function :
>
>  $f(x) = \frac{127 x^9}{20160}-\frac{251 x^8}{1008}+\frac{5957 x^7}{1440}-\frac{6757 x^6}{180}+\frac{582289 x^5}{2880}-\frac{94475 x^4}{144}+\frac{693097 x^3}{560}-\frac{170819 x^2}{140}+472 x$
>  
>  [See it on Wolfsram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=472%20x%20-%20(170819%20x%5E2)%2F140%20%2B%20(693097%20x%5E3)%2F560%20-%20(94475%20x%5E4)%2F144%20%2B%20(582289%20x%5E5)%2F2880%20-%20(6757%20x%5E6)%2F180%20%2B%20(5957%20x%5E7)%2F1440%20-%20(251%20x%5E8)%2F1008%20%2B%20(127%20x%5E9)%2F20160)) 
>  
>  Starting with $n = 0$, each number in the sequence $S(n)$ is $f(n)$.
>
>  By this logic, the 30th element of the sequence has $n = 29$. Thus the 30th element is $f(29) = 28141044420$.

Comment: How on earth did you figure this out?! I can't even figure out if it makes sense, but if it does, it's amazing if you did it without complete automation.

Comment: @SendersReagent Likely by fitting a polynomial to the sequence (solving for $a_i$ in $f(x) = a_1 x + \ldots + a_9 x^9$ - we have 9 unknowns and 9 equations so there is always a solution). This is very likely not the answer OP is thinking of but it illustrates the mathematical ambiguity in defining a sequence solely by the first $N$ terms: there are infinitely many functions that can match this.

Answer (score 1):

Answer

> 116

Explanation

> $f(0) = 0, f(1) = 2, f(2) = 4, f(3) = 12, f(4) = 8, f(5) = 20...$
>
> $f(k) = 2 * k$, if $k = 2^x$ see that $f(2) = 4, f(4) = 8, f(8) = 16$
> $f(k) = k * (k+1)$, if $k + 1 = 2^x$ see that $f(1) = 1*2, f(3) = 3*4, f(7) = 7 * 8$
>  $f(k) = k * 4$ otherwise
>  The 30th element is $f(29)$ so $f(29) = 29 * 4 = 116$ because $29 ≠ 2^x$ and $30 ≠ 2^x$